# Can't Assign Outlook Retention Policy

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, retention-policy

We have a notifications@ourdomain.com email account which we use for our apps and services for sending emails to clients. Last week, all the emails stopped going out because the mailbox was full (primarily everything in the `Sent Items` folder).

I went in and cleaned up years worth of old emails, and then purged the `Deleted Items`, which freed up space, and the emails started going out again.

Obviously though, we want to prevent this from happening again. So I am trying to assign a retention policy to purge older emails.

I logged in to [outlook.office365.com](https://outlook.office365.com) with the account. I right click on the **Folders** node, > `Assign Policy` > `1 Week Delete` . It seems to take it, and if I right click on **Folders** again and check, it still has it selected, but if I refresh the page, or log out/log in again, then it is reset to just **Use parent folder policy**.

From what I've read, if I didn't have the rights to set a retention policy, then the `Assign Policy` menu item wouldn't even show up. So I believe that (as this account) I should have rights to set the policy. But how do I get it to stick?

[image]

Comment: I would look to setting retention policies from the admin center: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/messaging-records-management/create-a-retention-policy

Answer (score 1):

> From what I've read, if I didn't have the rights to set a retention
> policy, then the Assign Policy menu item wouldn't even show up.

In my lab you should still be able to see the **Assign Policy** option (only with **User parent folder policy**) when this mailbox does not have a retention policy assigned.

Explain in screenshots:

1.In Exchange Admin Center this mailbox does not have retention policy assigned

[image]

[image]

2.In Outlook on the web you can still see this option

[image]

3.Another mailbox which has retention policy assigned, you can see the retention labels correctly (Personal 1 year move to archive)

[image]

So I would start from contacting your Exchange administrator and have him confirm if this mailbox still has a Exchange retention policy assigned.

If yes, have a check of the current retention labels included in the retention policy.

The relationship between Retention policy and Retention labels:

[Retention tags and retention policies in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/messaging-records-management/retention-tags-and-policies)